# post callback function synchronization

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables and after post I want to refresh the page after changes in the database are done. But for now it's pretty much random if the page refreshes before or after the database is updated. I also tried to add 'success:' to the callback function but this doesn't help.

Script for datatables projects.php:

```
    <script> $(document).ready( function () { 
var projects = $('#projects').DataTable({
        paging:true,    dom: 'Blfrtip',     colReorder: true,   select: {style: 'single'},
        buttons: [
            {
                    text: 'Edit',
                    action: function () {   
                        $projectID = $(projects.row('.selected').node()).data('id');                       
                        if ($projectID === undefined)
                        {
                            alert("Please select a project.");
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = "../projects/editProject.php?projectID=" + $projectID;
                        }
                    }
             },
             {
                    text: 'Add',
                    action: function () {   
                        window.location.href = "../projects/addProject.php";                
                    }
             },
             {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    action: function () {   
                        $projectID = $(projects.row('.selected').node()).data('id');                       
                        if ($projectID === undefined)
                        {
                            alert("Please select a project.");
                        } else {
                            $.post("../projects/deleteProject.php",
                            {
                                projectID: $projectID,  
                                function() {
                                    window.location.reload(true);
                                }           
                            }
                            );                                            
                        }
                    }
             }
        ] }); } ); </script>
```

deleteProject.php:

```
<?php
require("../database/dbService.php");
require("../projects/deleteProjectService.php");

session_start();
$connection = connectToDB();

// check if input data is set
if (!isset($_POST['projectID'])){
    header("Location: ../projects/projects.php");   
    exit;   
}

// input data
$projectID = $_POST['projectID'];

deleteProject($connection, $projectID);
$_SESSION['message'] = "The project has been deleted!";


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed callback function in the wrong place, it should have been:

```js
$.post(
   "../projects/deleteProject.php",
   { projectID: $projectID },
   function(){ window.location.reload(true); }           
);
```